# special case - deleting rows on excel (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet, and the worksheet has multiple columns,multiple rows. How can I create a script such that, if a cell in any of those columns does not have  a phrase, for example,'cat', the whole row gets deleted?

There are many solutions online, but they usually ask you to define a range, such as which column you want to search in and until how many rows. I can't have these restrictions as my different worksheets have different columns and different number of rows, but the same concept, where I delete a row if a certain phrase isn't existent in that row.

Comment: Just to make sure, you need every cell in a row to have the word "cat" in it and if even once cell doesn't the whole row goes? How many columns do you need to check?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the word ***cat*** must appear somewhere in the row.  If the row is completely "feline-free" then that row will be deleted.  Here is a typical approach:

```
Sub KeepOnlyCatRows()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, s As String, c As String
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    c = Chr(1)
    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        s = c & Application.WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(c, True, Rows(i)) & c
        If InStr(s, c & "cat" & c) = 0 Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**NOTES:**

- If the word *cat* must appear in every cell in the row, then ignore this answer.
- I am assuming that the "cat-cell" contains only the word *cat* and no other text.

**EDIT#1:**

In order to allow an arbitrary word rather than *cat*, try the following:

```
Sub KeepOnlySpecialRows()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, s As String, c As String
    Dim SpecialWord As String
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    c = Chr(1)
    SpecialWord = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the special word:", Type:=2)
    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        s = c & Application.WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(c, True, Rows(i)) & c
        If InStr(s, c & SpecialWord & c) = 0 Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: i meant cat as an example, is there a way such that instead of hardcoding cat into the code, we can allow us to take in ANY word and perform the same function as your program?

Comment: @rahk  See my **EDIT#1**